# Where can I put Logging mechanism on my code

Tags: asp.net, logging, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net mvc applicaiton and I am new about cross cutting concers. So I need to know where can I use my logger code following example.

I have an interface that logs erros. I am implementing this interface on my code.

```
public interface ILogger { void Log(Exception exception); }
```

So I have Controller, ProductService, ProductRepository classes.

```
public interface ProductController: ApiController{

     public IHttpActionResult Get(){
            try {
                productService.GetProducts();
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.Log(e); // 1-Should I use logging in here?
            }
     }
}
```

Product service;

```
public class ProductService{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts(){
            try {
                productRepository.GetAll();
            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.Log(e); // 2-Should I use logging in here?
            }
    }   
}
```

In repository.

```
public class ProductRepository{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAll(){
            try {

            }catch(Exception e){
                logger.Log(e); // 3-Should I use logging in here?
            }
    }   
}
```

I could not determine where can I use logging code. Or add logging in everywhere.

Comment: You should use MVC 3 tier architecture. You have to call a service from controller which will refer to the repository which should be responsible for logging.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement custom exception filter.

```
public class LogExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public ILogger logger { get; set; }
    public LogExceptionAttribute(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var exception = actionExecutedContext.Exception;
        logger.Log(actionExecutedContext.Exception);

        // You could also send client a message about exception.
        actionExecutedContext.Response =
                actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Then register it on global level.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new LogExceptionAttribute(Logger));
```

This filter would be called for any unhandled exception thrown from controller method.

Comment: So if an exception occures in service or repository implementation, I will catch in ExceptionFilter. But I will return user a userfriendly message about exceptions.